# matplotlib legend: scatterplot colours not what I was expecting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm making a scatterplot from some data in a pandas dataframe, which has the columns `year`, `name`, `ttotal` and `ftotal`. I'm plotting `year` against `ftotal/ttotal` using matplotlib, and attempting to colour each point according to its name, which seems to be working mostly.

However, I'm trying to get the legend in my matplotlib to match up to the colours in the list `competition_colours`, but for some reason, four of my labels (marteau, oistrakh_A, oistrakh_B, oistrakh_C) in the legend aren't appearing as the colours I expected. Anyone have any ideas why? The code screenshot is below.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

fixed: turns out I needed to put `[]` around the value of the `c` parameter in `plt.scatter()`.